# Can alarm(int) override sleep(int) in C?

Tags: signals, fork, handler, sleep, alarm

I've created a `signal handler` for `alarm()`. The parent forks out another process which will not have the pending alarm signal. So, the alarm is only invoked in the parent process.
But as the `alarm(2)` is invoked, it overrides the `sleep(10)` in the parent process. Parent only waits for 2 seconds before printing :

```
"parent retval=8"
```

Whereas the child waits 10 seconds. Why does the `alarm()` signal override `sleep()` and does sleep return anything (obviously it does in this case, but why? `sleep()` shouldn't return anything, right?)?

The code is given below.

```
<headers>

pid_t cpid;

int main() {
    int retval;
    signal(SIGALRM, handler);
    alarm(2);
    if ((cpid = fork()) == 0) {
        printf(“I’m the child\n”);
        retval = sleep(10);
        printf(“child retval=%d\n”, retval);
    }
    else {
        printf(“I’m the parent\n”);
        retval = sleep(10);
        printf(“parent retval=%d\n”, retval);
    }
}

/* Handle SIGALRM */
void handler(int sig)
{
    if (cpid == 0)
        printf(“running child handler\n”);
    else
        printf(“running parent handler\n”);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sleep returns 0 or the number of seconds remaining to be slept if it returns early. Also, the man page indicates that mixing sleep and alarm is a bad idea.

```
NAME
   sleep - Sleep for the specified number of seconds

SYNOPSIS
   #include <unistd.h>

   unsigned int sleep(unsigned int seconds);

DESCRIPTION
   sleep() makes the calling process sleep until seconds seconds have elapsed or a signal arrives which is not ignored.

RETURN VALUE
   Zero if the requested time has elapsed, or the number of seconds left to sleep, if the call was interrupted by a signal handler.

CONFORMING TO
   POSIX.1-2001.

BUGS
   sleep() may be implemented using SIGALRM; mixing calls to alarm(2) and sleep() is a bad idea.

   Using longjmp(3) from a signal handler or modifying the handling of SIGALRM while sleeping will cause undefined results.

SEE ALSO
   alarm(2), signal(2), signal(7)
```

Comment: Thanks! I was confused with what effects alarm would have on sleep but its clear now!

Answer (score 0):

Return of sleep():

0   The thread slept for the full time specified.

value   The thread did not sleep the full time because of a signal whose action is to run a signal-catching function, to end the request, or to terminate the process. The value returned is the number of seconds remaining in the specified sleep time; that is, the value of seconds minus the actual number of seconds that the thread was suspended.

-1  sleep() was not successful. The errno variable is set to indicate the error.

when  child is create the Alarm will not inherit in child process.